# Spring Boot Data Problem on save entity on element to list changes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm, spring-data

As I was updating a list of something under JSONB (postgresql) I noticed that a change to a JSONB list (which is materialized by a list of DTO in Java @Entity, and its @Type annotation over...) was not persisted though an element of the list was updated.
Nevertheless, changing the reference to that list with new ArrayList<>(myPreviousList) lead to persisting the changes in database.

I think the problem is not that linked to the database implementation... but more to the orm bridge, that thinks that a list of element with same references is not to be changed. Or I missed something perhaps?

Using Spring-Boot v2.0.6

EDIT: the changes were actually into a nested list of that list above, but I think the problem still remains :D

EDIT: Actually it's when I update another column of that table that the save is effective. And it also a JSONB type

Please advise

Best regards

Comment: I'm sorry but it's difficult to follow what you wrote. Could you maybe simplify by posting some sort of pseudocode, or even the code you're using

Comment: Wait, do you call the "save" method of your Spring Data Repository?

Comment: Yes for sure I call the save method

Comment: Actually it's when I update another column of that table that the save is effective. Otherwise nothing, the table don't move 

Comment: I'll provide a code sample as soon as possible...

Comment: Thanks. I need a bit of code to give you a decent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved as it was a nested object that override `equals()` method and so the entity property was always considered not changed.

Thank you for your help all